# How do I style the output from this async await function that successfully fetches data from a database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
<script>
        getData();

        async function getData() {
          const response = await fetch("/members");
          const data = await response.json();

          for (item of data) {
            const root = document.createElement("div");
            const member = document.createElement("div");
            member.textContent = `member: ${item.member}`;

            root.append(
              item.firstname,
              item.lastname,
              item.mobile,
              item.contactname,
              item.contactphone
            );
            document.body.append(root);
          }
          console.log(data);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, John. Is your question about how do style output, or are you asking for opinions? The reason I ask, is that StackOverflow is more about answering how-to questions. They really don't like subjective questions.

Comment: Hello Sue, Yes, this is a 'how-to' question. Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

The same way you style anything else. Write a CSS rule. Add whatever classes (e.g. `member.classList.add("foo")`), etc.  you need to design a specific enough selector to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to it with `member.classList.add('member-item')`

example

```html
<head>
<style> 
.member-item {
background-color: white;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root" />
<script>
       const root = document.querySelector('#root')

async function getData() {
  // const response = await fetch("/members");
  // const data = await response.json();
  const sampleData = [{
    firstName: 'Dave',
    lastname: 'Smith',
    mobile: '0632452345',
    contactname: 'Dave',
    contactphone: '0632452345',
  },
                     {
    firstName: 'Mike',
    lastname: 'Smith',
    mobile: '06324234345',
    contactname: 'Mike',
    contactphone: '0635435345',
  }]

for(let i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i+= 1) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `
<p>First Name ${sampleData[i].firstName}</p>
<p>Last Name ${sampleData[i].lastname}</p>
<p>mobile Name ${sampleData[i].mobile}</p>
<p>Contact Name ${sampleData[i].contactname}</p>
<p>Contact Phone ${sampleData[i].contactphone}</p>
<hr>
`;
  root.append(div)
}
}

getData()
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, Lucjan. What I really should have asked was: How I get this data into a HTML table? Thanks, John